# Pass mono as a header value in ServerResponse

Tags: java, spring, mono, spring-webflux

I'm new to functional endpoints/spring webflux and I'm trying to return mono as a header value but I couldn't find a way to do it as the `header` method accepts only the string.

Router function,

```
@Bean
RouterFunction<ServerResponse> productRoutes() {
    return route(GET("/products").and(accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)), getAllProductsHandler());
}
```

Handler function,

```
private HandlerFunction<ServerResponse> getAllProductsHandler() {
    return req -> {

        // Here the products and the totalProducts are being returned from the service layer 

        Flux<Product> products = Flux.just(new Product("123"), new Product("234"));
        Mono<Integer> totalProducts = Mono.just(2);

        return ok()
                .header("totalCount", totalProducts)
                .body(products, Product.class);
    };
}
```

What is the right way to return mono as a header value here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By chaining on the mono and build your response.

```
final Mono<Integer> totalProducts = Mono.just(2);

return totalProducts.flatMap(value -> ok()
                .header("totalCount", value)
                .body(products, Product.class)
        );
```